# Invoke PublishProgress() from a callback yet invoked from AsyncTask

Tags: android, callback, android-asynctask, xamarin.android, xamarin

After 3 years of reading it's my 1st post here. There never was a need to write one. It's a very good site here.

---

I got the idea to extend the native `AsyncTask` class to support callbacks invoked from `RunInBackground()`, `OnProgressUpdate()`, `OnPreExecute()` and `OnPostExecute()`. So I have no need to implement a new `AsyncTask` descendant for every single task.

(I have to mention that in `Java` is an method called `DoInBackground()` which also exist in the Xamarin port. But the documentation says to override `RunInBackground()` instead.)

The target is to instatiate the `AsyncTask` descendant, to set the needed callbacks and to execute the `AsyncTask`.

Now the problem is, that I need to call `PublishProgress()` from inside the callback in the activity to react on changing progress states. So I have to pass a seperate callback to this method into the callback of `RunInBackground()`. But when I do that there will be thrown an exception.

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
---> System.Exception:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

But I can't handle this, because I don't know which reference should be needed. The debugging made clear the callback is passed right.

Activity: **Main.cs**

```cs
using AsyncSpecial = AsyncTaskEnhanced< System.String, System.Int32, System.Int32 >;

[ Activity( Label = "FooBar", MainLauncher = true ) ]
public class Main : Activity
{
  protected Int32 RunInBackground( AsyncSpecial.PublishProgressDelegate publishProgressCallback, params String[] arguments )
  {
    for ( Int32 n = 0; n < arguments.Length; n++ )
    {
      Console.WriteLine( "Item :: " + arguments[ n ] );
      // Won't invoke.
      PublishProgressDelegate( n );
      // Won't invoke.
      DelegateHelper.Invoke( publishProgressCallback, n );
    }
    return arguments.Length;
  }

  protected void OnProgressUpdate( Int32 progress )
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "Progress :: " + progress );
  }

  protected void OnPreExecute( )
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "Pre" );
  }

  protected void OnPostExecute( Int32 result )
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "Result :: " + result );
  }

  protected override void OnCreate( Bundle bundle )
  {
    base.OnCreate( bundle );
    this.SetContentView( Resource.Layout.Main );
    Button button = this.FindViewById< Button >( Resource.Id.btnOne );
    button.Click += ( Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs ) =>
    {
      AsyncSpecial asyncTask = new AsyncSpecial( );
      asyncTask.RunInBackgroundCallback = this.RunInBackground;
      asyncTask.OnProgressUpdateCallback = this.OnProgressUpdate;
      asyncTask.OnPreExecuteCallback = this.OnPreExecute;
      asyncTask.OnPostExecuteCallback = this.OnPostExecute;
      asyncTask.Execute( "ItemOne", "ItemTwo" );
    };
  }
}
```

Class: **AsyncTaskEnhanced.cs**

```cs
public class AsyncTaskEnhanced< TArgument, TProgress, TResult > : AsyncTask< TArgument, TProgress, TResult >
{
  public delegate void PublishProgressDelegate( params TProgress[ ] progresses );
  public delegate TResult RunInBackgroundDelegate( PublishProgressDelegate publishProgressCallback, params TArgument[ ] arguments );
  public delegate void OnProgressUpdateDelegate( TProgress progress );
  public delegate void OnPreExecuteDelegate( );
  public delegate void OnPostExecuteDelegate( TResult result );

  private PublishProgressDelegate publishProgressCallback = null;
  public PublishProgressDelegate PublishProgressCallback
  { 
    get
    {
      return this.publishProgressCallback; 
    }
    set
    {
      this.publishProgressCallback = value; 
    }
  }

  private RunInBackgroundDelegate runInBackgroundCallback = null;
  public RunInBackgroundDelegate RunInBackgroundCallback
  { 
    get
    {
      return this.runInBackgroundCallback; 
    }
    set
    {
      this.runInBackgroundCallback = value; 
    }
  }

  private OnProgressUpdateDelegate onProgressUpdateCallback = null;
  public OnProgressUpdateDelegate OnProgressUpdateCallback
  { 
    get
    {
      return this.onProgressUpdateCallback; 
    }
    set
    {
      this.onProgressUpdateCallback = value; 
    }
  }

  private OnPreExecuteDelegate onPreExecuteCallback = null;
  public OnPreExecuteDelegate OnPreExecuteCallback
  { 
    get
    {
      return this.onPreExecuteCallback; 
    }
    set
    {
      this.onPreExecuteCallback = value; 
    }
  }

  private OnPostExecuteDelegate onPostExecuteCallback = null;
  public OnPostExecuteDelegate OnPostExecuteCallback
  { 
    get
    {
      return this.onPostExecuteCallback; 
    }
    set
    {
      this.onPostExecuteCallback = value; 
    }
  }

  public AsyncTaskEnhanced( IntPtr doNotUse, JniHandleOwnership transfer ) : base( doNotUse, transfer )
  {
    this.PublishProgressCallback = this.PublishProgress;
  }

  public AsyncTaskEnhanced( ) : base( )
  {
  }

  protected override TResult RunInBackground( params TArgument[ ] arguments )
  {
    TResult result = DelegateHelper.Invoke< TResult >( this.RunInBackgroundCallback, this.PublishProgressCallback, arguments );
    return result;
  }

  protected void OnProgressUpdate( TProgress progress )
  {
    DelegateHelper.Invoke( this.OnProgressUpdateCallback, progress );
  }

  protected override void OnPreExecute( )
  {
    DelegateHelper.Invoke( this.OnPreExecuteCallback );
  }

  protected override void OnPostExecute( TResult result )
  {
    DelegateHelper.Invoke( this.OnPostExecuteCallback, result );
  }
}
```

Class: **DelegateHelper.cs**

```cs
static public class DelegateHelper
{
  static public void Invoke( Delegate callback, params Object[ ] arguments )
  {
    if ( null != callback )
    {
      callback.DynamicInvoke( arguments );
    }
  }

  static public TResult Invoke< TResult >( Delegate callback, params Object[ ] arguments )
  {
    TResult result = default( TResult );
    if ( null != callback )
    {
      result = ( TResult ) callback.DynamicInvoke( arguments );
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

BTW: If I call `PublishProgress()` from inside `AsyncTaskEnhanced::RunInBackground()` then `AsyncTaskEnhanced::OnProgressUpdate()` will not be invoked. This is much confusing to me.

I hope I made myself and my needs clear enough.

Thanks alot.
Christian

Comment: Please post your findings as an answer to your own question and accept it if it was the solution, instead of adding it to your original post. That suits the StackOverflow Q&A style better. Also I would think using the C# classes for Tasks and Threads would be a lot cleaner and easier to implement. I suspect that you are using this just for updating a progress bar of some sort?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I'll edit the post and make a separate answere instead. I will try the usage of the C# classes, but I don't know if it will work in Android then. I want one threading class for any purposes. I could instatiate many tasks and stack them into a task queue with priorities. The callback solution will realize this with one class instead of many derived classes. Actually I have one problem left. I can't find an answere why `PublishProgress()` doesn't invoke `OnUpdateProgress()`. It doesn't matter, if it's called in the callback or (for test) in the task itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I'm late. Official work comes first.
As suggested by @Cheesebaron I separated my first answere.

---

1.

Ok. I solved one problem. I forgot to set the `PublishProgressCallback` in the argumentless constructor of `AsyncTaskEnhanced`. So the first call of `PublishProgress( n )` in the `RunInBackground()` callback works properly without an exception (except it still doesn't call `OnProgressUpdate()`) but the invocation during the `DelegateHelper` fails with an

```
System.Exception:
Failed to convert parameters.
```

I have to take a look on it. My first impression says it should work and it's just a simple thing I have to figure out.

---

2.

I didn't figure it out, why `PublishProgress()` does not invoke `OnPublishProgress()` It seems to be a problem of the Xamarin port itself. As further suggested by @Cheesebaron I used the .NET native possibilities. They work great and offers more flexibility as the `AsyncTask` class does.

First the delegate helper, used to invoke a callback without explicit in-code checking if any handlers are attached to the delegate.

```
using System;

namespace Library
{
  static public class HDelegate
  {
    #region Methods

    static public void Invoke( Delegate callback, params Object[ ] arguments )
    {
      if ( null != callback )
      {
        callback.DynamicInvoke( arguments );
      }
    }

    static public TResult Invoke< TResult >( Delegate callback, params Object[ ] arguments )
    {
      TResult result = default( TResult );
      if ( null != callback )
      {
        result = ( TResult ) callback.DynamicInvoke( arguments );
      }
      return result;
    }

    #endregion
  }
}
```

And here's the implementation of the `AsyncTask` clone.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Library.Threading
{
  public class CallbackThread< TArgument, TProgress, TResult >
  {
    #region Delegates

    public delegate void PublishProgressDelegate( params TProgress[ ] progresses );
    public delegate TResult DoInBackgroundDelegate( PublishProgressDelegate publishProgressCallback, params TArgument[ ] arguments );
    public delegate void ProgressUpdateDelegate( TProgress progress );
    public delegate void PreExecuteDelegate( );
    public delegate void PostExecuteDelegate( TResult result );

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    private PublishProgressDelegate publishProgressCallback = null;
    protected virtual PublishProgressDelegate PublishProgressCallback
    { 
      get
      {
        return this.publishProgressCallback; 
      }
      set
      {
        this.publishProgressCallback = value; 
      }
    }

    private DoInBackgroundDelegate doInBackgroundCallback = null;
    public virtual DoInBackgroundDelegate DoInBackgroundCallback
    { 
      get
      {
        return this.doInBackgroundCallback; 
      }
      set
      {
        this.doInBackgroundCallback = value; 
      }
    }

    private ProgressUpdateDelegate progressUpdateCallback = null;
    public virtual ProgressUpdateDelegate ProgressUpdateCallback
    { 
      get
      {
        return this.progressUpdateCallback; 
      }
      set
      {
        this.progressUpdateCallback = value; 
      }
    }

    private PreExecuteDelegate preExecuteCallback = null;
    public virtual PreExecuteDelegate PreExecuteCallback
    { 
      get
      {
        return this.preExecuteCallback; 
      }
      set
      {
        this.preExecuteCallback = value; 
      }
    }

    private PostExecuteDelegate postExecuteCallback = null;
    public virtual PostExecuteDelegate PostExecuteCallback
    { 
      get
      {
        return this.postExecuteCallback; 
      }
      set
      {
        this.postExecuteCallback = value; 
      }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public CallbackThread( )
    {
      this.PublishProgressCallback = this.PublishProgress;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    protected virtual void PreExecute( )
    {
      HDelegate.Invoke( this.PreExecuteCallback );
    }

    protected virtual TResult DoInBackground( params TArgument[ ] arguments )
    {
      TResult result = HDelegate.Invoke< TResult >( this.DoInBackgroundCallback, this.PublishProgressCallback, arguments );
      return result;
    }

    protected virtual void PublishProgress( params TProgress[ ] progresses )
    {
      foreach ( TProgress progress in progresses )
      {
        this.ProgressUpdate( progress );
      }
    }

    protected virtual void ProgressUpdate( TProgress progress )
    {
      HDelegate.Invoke( this.ProgressUpdateCallback, progress );
    }

    protected virtual void PostExecute( TResult result )
    {
      HDelegate.Invoke( this.PostExecuteCallback, result );
    }

    public virtual void Execute( params TArgument[ ] arguments )
    {
      Thread thread = new Thread(( ) =>
      {
        this.PreExecute( );
        TResult result = this.DoInBackground( arguments );
        this.PostExecute( result );
      } );
      thread.Start( );
    }

    #endregion
  }
}
```

`HDelegate` and `CallbackThread` sure implement simplest needs. But they also introduce some benefits. It's now possible to use one implementation for several purposes while callbacks can be used. These callbacks are multi delegates, too. So several actions can be invoked in chain.